# How to disable onclick of a class

Tags: javascript, onclick

I would like to know how to disable the onclick event of a certain class. I am aware that you can use the CSS `pointer-events: none;` however I would like for the hover events to still work, just onclick to be disabled.

Also how do I re-enable them later? For example:

```
if (document.getElementById('wuzi').backgroundColor == "green" ) {
 //disable onclick
 } else {
 //enable onclick
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can just add and remove the listener to 'click':

```
var wuzi = document.getElementById('wuzi');
if (wuzi.backgroundColor === "green" ) {
  wuzi.removeEventListener('click');
} else {
  wuzi.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
```

where *clickHandler* is your function for handling the click.

Comment: what is the difference between adding event listener click and the "onclick" function. Also if I were to have multiple functions which could trigger on click (dependent on the class of the element), would I list them all in the "do stuff here" section?

Comment: You can use onclick but only one handler may be registered using this; the docs advise using addEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick (see Notes section).

Comment: could you explain what clickHandler is? Is it a pre-defined function?

Comment: Sorry, the line containing 'do stuff' was erroneous; you can just assign the handlers within the 'else' case. I would normally define the handlers as functions rather than inline, but it depends on the complexity.

Comment: clickHandler would be the function that handles your click (performs whatever you want to happen on the click event); I couldn't see it in your original example so just stubbed it.

Comment: ok thanks for explaining that. Time to ask a bit more of a complex question. Lets say that "wuzi" was a class name and I have 8 boxes which are "wuzi" and 8 which are "luzi". 

lets focus on this line `wuzi.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);` 
I have 5 other classes which are added to wuzi or luzi (randomly allocated), so I can end up with "wuzi cool" "wuzi lame" "wuzi happy".

I have functions directly related to the onclick of "cool" "lame" or "happy". So how would I enable the clicks for wuzi by running functions that search for the "cool" "lame" and "happy" classnames

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure what you mean - if you need to attach specific handlers you'll need to select the specific elements by class using document.getElementsByClassName (http://devdocs.io/dom/document/getelementsbyclassname). You can then attach specific handlers?

Comment: I've created an example here: https://jsbin.com/pogamolice/edit?html,js,console,output  I don't think it's exactly what you want (I'm not sure I understand what that is) but it does show adding specific handlers plus one to all 'wuzis'. Hopefully it's a start that you can adapt?

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below:

```
var element = document.getElementById('wuzi')
    if (element .backgroundColor == "green" ) {
     //disable onclick
       element.onclick = '';
     } else {
     //enable onclick
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add CSS class instead of comparing `backgroundColor`, then check set `disabled` property based on class

```
var element = document.getElementById('wuzi');
element.disabled = element.classList.contains("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

try returning false onclick:

```
var element = document.getElementById('wuzi')
    if (element .backgroundColor == "green" ) {
     //disable onclick by returning false from onclick
       element.onclick = return false;
     } else {
     //enable onclick or do some appropriate action
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will helps you

```
 if (document.getElementById('wuzi').style.backgroundColor === "green" ) {
 //disable onclick

 this.onclick=null
 } else {
 //enable onclick
 this.onclick=my_function;
}
```

Just define your function as you want

```
 function my_function()
{
    alert('enable');
}
```